# Elasticsearch v6.0.1 Nodejs boost match with one of arrays elements

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch, boost

In my project I have user objects like this.

```
{
  "_id": "1",
  "username": "RAggro",
  "name": "Vardan Tadevosyan"
},
{
  "_id": "2",
  "username": "XACHIK",
  "name": "XACHIK"
},
{
  "_id": "3",
  "username": "vardar",
  "name": "Vardan Gukoyan"
},
{
  "_id": "4",
  "username": "Gordey",
  "name": "Gordey Gordeev"
},
{
  "_id": "5",
  "username": "id220107973",
  "name": "Vardan Ayvazyan"
},
{
  "_id": "6",
  "username": "vvardanyan4",
  "name": "Vardan Vardanyan"
},
{
  "_id": "7",
  "username": "svardan",
  "name": "Vardan Sargsyan"
}
```

And I have list of _id-s, like [51,3,9,11,6, 2].

I whant to query users by 'name' and 'username', orderid like first comes users that contains in ids array then others

```
query: {
     multi_match: {
                query: "vardan",
                fields: ["name", "username"],
                operator: "or"
            },
     boosting: {
        positive: {
            term: {
                _id: [51,3,9,11,6, 2]
            }
        },
        positive_boost: 2.0
    }
   }
```

So the expected result is:

```
{
  "_id": "3",
  "username": "vardar",
  "name": "Vardan Gukoyan"
},
{
  "_id": "6",
  "username": "vvardanyan4",
  "name": "Vardan Vardanyan"
},
{
  "_id": "1",
  "username": "RAggro",
  "name": "Vardan Tadevosyan"
},
{
  "_id": "5",
  "username": "id220107973",
  "name": "Vardan Ayvazyan"
},
{
  "_id": "7",
  "username": "svardan",
  "name": "Vardan Sargsyan"
}
```

But I'm fetching empty array,
Please, help how can I modify my query to reach expected ordered result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it easily using a `bool/should` clause that will boost the documents whose IDs are within the specified group:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "vardan",
            "fields": [
              "name",
              "username"
            ],
            "operator": "or"
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "ids": {
            "values": ["51","3","9","11","6","2"]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: With 'should' it returns empty array.
Without 'should' not ordered array.

Comment: Can you show a sample document that should match? A real one (with `_id` and `_source`), not one made up as above.

Comment: ` { _index: 'new_users',
      _type: 'user',
      _id: '5b558b5dfb9b94000438cd10',
      _score: null,
      _source:
       { name: 'Vardan Tadevosyan',
         username: 'RAggro',
         region: 'en-US',
         email: 'vtadevosyan@gmail.com' },
      sort: [ 1533393748654 ] } `

Comment: And you're using `5b558b5dfb9b94000438cd10` in the `ids` should clause?

Comment: Yes.

And I need array ordered like first comes users that contains in ids array then others.

Comment: With **ids** inside 'should' it returns not sorted array, and when I changed it with **_id**  it returns empty array.

Comment: What the query does is that from all the results you get, the ones with the specified ids appear first in the results (but not necessarily in the same order as specified in the array), but definitely before other documents with ids **not specified in the array**

Comment: Also note that `ids` is the name of a query, which you can find here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-ids-query.html

Comment: Ok, I understood it. And tried again with **ids**.
Then tried to change array elements types from mongoose ObjectId to simple string, nothing changed the response is not sorted like I want.

Comment: Do you mind creating a gist with all the steps so I can reproduce what you have?

Comment: Hey **Val** , thanks for help :) .
It works using this query: `query:{
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "multi_match": {
                    "query": "vardan",
                    "fields": [
                        "name",
                        "username"
                    ],
                    "operator": "or"
                }
            }],
            "should": [{
                "terms": {
                    "_id": ["51","3","9","11","6","2"],
                    "boost": 100
                }
            }]
        }
    }`

Answer (score 0):

It works using this query:

```
{
    query:{
            "bool": {
                "must": [{
                    "multi_match": {
                        "query": "vardan",
                        "fields": [
                            "name",
                            "username"
                        ],
                        "operator": "or"
                    }
                }],
                "should": [{
                    "terms": {
                        "_id": ["51","3","9","11","6","2"],
                        "boost": 100
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    }
```